# Sliding Divs with Percentage Widths

Tags: jquery

I have 2 divs, 70% and 30% widths, within a 100% width containing div. On click I want the 70% div to change to 100% width and 'slide over' the 30% div and on second click retract back to 70% and reinstate the 30% div. I've half achieved the desired effect below; it 'slides over' the smaller div but retains it's 70% width. I can't get the width to expand to 100% without having a stutter animation as I've invoked the width change after the toggle or it expanding to 100% but the other 30% div still being visible and knocking the divs onto 2 lines.

http://jsfiddle.net/establish/scKf2/

I did see another similar question that works but they are static widths and I couldn't successfully convert them into percentages without the above problems cropping up again.

http://jsfiddle.net/establish/kjDYh/

**HTML**

```
<div id='ember'>

<div id='sidebar'>
</div>

<div id='activity'>
    <a href='#' id='trigger'>Nav</a>
</div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#sidebar { 
background-color: green; 
float: left;
height: 200px;
position: relative;
z-index: 5;
width: 30%;
}

#activity { 
background-color: purple; 
float: left;
height: 200px;
position: relative;
z-index: 10;
width: 70%;
}

a { 
color: white;
display: block; 
padding: 12px; 
text-decoration: none;
}
```

**JS - First Attempt**

```
$('#trigger').click(function() {

$('#sidebar').animate({width: 'toggle'});

});​
```

**JS - Second Attempt**

```
$('#trigger').toggle(function() {
    $('#sidebar').animate({width: '+=22em'});
    $('#activity').animate({width: '-=22em'});
},function() {
    $('#sidebar').animate({width: '-=22em'});
    $('#activity').animate({width: '+=22em'});
});​
```

​

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/kjDYh/2/

basically set the nav to 0px and main to 100%?

```
$('#trigger').toggle(function() {
    $('#sidebar').animate({width: '100%'});
    $('#activity').animate({width: '0px'});
},function() {
    $('#sidebar').animate({width: '70%'});
    $('#activity').animate({width: '30%'});
});​
```

Comment: Oops you may have to swap the #sidebar and #activity widths round

Comment: Bah, simple in the end. Thanks!

Comment: why never thought of using `0px` rather than `0%`. +1

Answer (score 0):

Why not just set the width % in your jquery call?

```
$('#trigger').click(function() {

    $('#sidebar').animate({width: '100%'});
    $('#activity').animate({width: '0px'});

});​
```

etc

Toggle, with new button to click back.

http://jsfiddle.net/zWxUj/10/

Comment: Sorry, I've edited it to explain it needed to switch back and forth

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#trigger').toggle(
    function() {
        $('#activity').animate({width: '100%'});
        $('#sidebar').animate({width: '0%'});
    },
    function() {
        $('#activity').animate({width: '70%'});
        $('#sidebar').animate({width: '30%'});
    });
```

Does this work?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scKf2/18/)

Comment: Haven't you just posted my jsfiddle example?